# XSL-FO - Empty block elements

Tags: xsl-fo

I have a quite simple template:

```
<xsl:template match="p">
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

How do I tell FO to keep empty lines even if the block is empty.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Just add a `<fo:leader/>` element at the end of your `<fo:block>`. Like this:

```
<xsl:template match="p">
        <fo:block>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
                <fo:leader />
        </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

The leader will do nothing for lines with content, and will create an empty line for lines without content.

Tested with Apache FOP and XEP.

Answer (score 11):

Or

```
<xsl:template match="p">
    <fo:block>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
            &#x00A0;
    </fo:block>
```

`&#x00A0;` is the equivalent of `&nbsp;` in HTML (actually `&nbsp;` is a XML entity that is defined as A0 which is the Unicode character for Non Breaking Space).

Answer (score 9):

Alternatively,

```
<fo:block white-space-treatment="preserve"> </fo:block>
```