# XSL-FO: Set fixed block height

Tags: height, block, xsl-fo

Is there any way I can set a fixed height for a block regardless of the content within it? I have a block which sometimes displays some text but sometimes it needs to be empty and keep the same height:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$condition">
       <fo:block height="30mm">
          <xsl:text>TEXTTEXT</xsl:text>
       </fo:block>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
       <fo:block height="30mm">
          <xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text>
       </fo:block>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: Did you specify any other formatting (e.g. line-height, font-size, space-after...) on this block? Or else, could it have inherited properties from a superordinate element?

Answer (score 13):

The `height` attribute does not apply to `fo:block`. To keep a fixed height, wrap the `fo:block` in a [`fo:block-container`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#fo_block-container):

```
<fo:block-container height="30mm">
 <fo:block>
   <xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text>
 </fo:block>
</fo:block-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

in place of empty text, you may pass **.**(*dot*) here. then height will remain and dot will ot displayed.its not proper solution but you may refer it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `fo:leader`, as mentioned in this stackoverflow QA:

[XSL-FO - Empty block elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082585/xsl-fo-empty-block-elements)

HTH!